# join three tables in firebirdsql

Tags: sql, join, firebird

I have that problem:
I'd like to join three table in order to get some values, for example:

```
Sellers
IDSELLERS
NAMESELLER

STOCK
IDSTOCK
QTYSTOCK
COST
FKSELLER

SELL
IDSELL
QTYSELL
PRICE
FKSELLER
```

I want to get out the total amount of `STOCK` and `SELL` tables for each seller

U have tried with the following query but it doubles the values for each sell:

```
select
SELLERS.NAMESELLER,
SUM(STOCK.QTY*STOCK.COST)AS STOCKS,
SUM(SELL.QTY*SELL.PRICE) AS SELLS
FROM
SELLERS
LEFT JOIN STOCK ON STOCK.FKSELLER=SELLERS.IDSELLER
LEFT JOIN SELL ON SELL.FKSELLER=SELLERS.IDSELLERS
GROUP BY
SELLERS.NAMESELLER
```

the firebirdsql release in use is the 2.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "doubles the values for each sell"? Some example data and output would be helpful. I have the feeling your model is wrong (eg why is a sale related to the seller, but not to the product sold)? In your current setup there can be N stock and M sell records, giving you N*M combinations of stock and sell.

Comment: hi mark, thanks for the reply,  from more tests, if the table stocks have three record for the sellers the values for the sum sell are triplicate and so on... 

the example are a simplified version of the table, the sell and the stock are related with product too.

i want from this query to know how much i have buyed from a seller and how much i have selled but don't interest what is the product interested, are only an economic value wich i wont.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if you have for example 2 rows in *sell* and 2 rows in *stock*. The first join will produce two rows, the second join will create 2*2 rows. Instead you should union the data and join once, or use a select expression to produce the sums.

Using a select expression:

```
select
  SELLERS.NAMESELLER,
  (select sum(STOCK.QTY * STOCK.COST) 
     from STOCK where STOCK.FKSELLER=SELLERS.IDSELLER) AS STOCKS,
  (select sum(SELL.QTY * SELL.PRICE) 
     from SELL where SELL.FKSELLER=SELLERS.IDSELLERS) AS SELLS
from SELLERS
```

Using a union:

```
select 
  SELLERS.NAMESELLER,
  sum(stocksell.STOCKQTY * stocksell.STOCKCOST) AS STOCKS,
  sum(stocksell.SELLQTY * stocksell.SELLPRICE) AS SELLS
from SELLERS
left join (
  select FKSELLER, QTY AS STOCKQTY, COST AS STOCKCOST, 
         0 AS SELLQTY, 0 AS SELLPRICE
  from STOCK
  union all
  select FKSELLER, 0 AS STOCKQTY, 0 AS STOCKCOST, 
         QTY AS SELLQTY, PRICE AS SELLPRICE
  from SELL
) stocksell
  ON stocksell.FKSELLER=SELLERS.IDSELLER
group by SELLERS.NAMESELLER
```

Comment: thanks Mark, it works perfectly, never used the select expression in firebird.